# I found a post that belongs to the Computer Science site. How do I flag it under triage review?

Tags: discussion

I am asked to review:
*[When visiting all nodes in increasing order of key value, is an AVL tree more efficient or a min-heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52985096/when-visiting-all-nodes-in-increasing-order-of-key-value-is-an-avl-tree-more-ef)*

To me it clearly belongs to *[Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/tour)*, because I found *https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/27860/whats-the-difference-between-a-binary-search-tree-and-a-binary-heap* that, to me clearly answers the question.

I have posted a comment, but how should I flag the post under Review Triage? Computer Science does not belong to the list of other Stack Exchange network sites.

(I have skipped it once very courageously, but it came back...)

After the input from @yivi the closest Off-Topic choice I could find was:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software
>   library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack
>   Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.
>   Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve
>   it.

Was it the obvious choice?

Answer (score 2):

If a question is off-topic here but on-topic in a different site, you flag it for closure (e.g click *"Unsalvageable"*).

When a site migration path is not available and the question is not on-topic here, the appropriate choice is to close the question.

That a question is on-topic in a different site is not reason enough to close a question, so if the question is actually off-topic here **you need select the offtopic reason that better applies**.

If you want you can leave a comment to make the poster aware of the possibility of deleting their post and reposting in a more appropriate site, but that's up to them.

Comment: I understand that. What I am looking for is the sub category Off-Topic. Which category do I choose. I can't just ask for closure I need a reason and the reason should be migrate... but I have to choose a exchange site and ... well the list does not contain Computer Science.

Comment: No, because that migration path doesn't exist. So you **do not choose migration**; instead you have to say for which reason this question is off-topic here.